# Extracting numbers starting with 3 specific digits and followed by minimum 2 more digits anywhere inside the string with regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a large string with various line breaks

```
Abc 90231 Test string
Lorem f90045zzzw, etc
90030 many items
079002
09011
09089goes on
```

I want to get als Substrings, which include 900|901|903 and followd minimum by two other numbers [0-9].

My current approach

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\(b900..|901..|902..|903..){5,}\b");
```

I want to get: `90231, 90045, 90030, 09089`
I do not want to get: `9002, 09011`

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean `@"\b90[0-3]\d{2,}\b"`? Get numbers that start with `900` - `903` and then contain 2 or more digits?

Comment: @"\b90[0-3]\d{2,}\b" does not find "90045" in f90045zzzw

Comment: Ok, that is just a word boundary issue, try `@"(?<!\d)90[0-3]\d{2,}"` (a digit boundary on the left).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```cs
(?<!\d)90[0-3]\d{2,}
```

The regex matches

- `(?<!\d)` - a left-hand digit boundary, no digit can appear on the left
- `90` - a `90` substring
- `[0-3]` - a digit from `0` to `3`
- `\d{2,}` - two or more digits.

To make `\d` only match ASCII digits, compile the regex with the `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DTibjg/1).

Comment: In case it should also match in the case where there are leading digits (e.g. `0090100`) you can just leave off the digit boundary `(?<!\d)`

Comment: @JeanotZubler Not sure about your comment, `f90045zzzw` contains the expected match and there is no way to use any other boundary. To truncate zeros, we usually consume them with `0*` and capture the rest of the number, but there is no need for this in the current pattern.

Comment: My comment was aimed at the fact, that we do not know the exact requirements of OP. It might be a requirement to get e.g. 90022 out of the string `f3790022zzw`. If this was the case, the digit boundary would be problematic.

Comment: @JeanotZubler Exactly in this case, it would be problematic to use a word boundary, `\b`, but not a **digit** boundary. The numbers are to start with `90`, then `0`, `1`, `2` or `3`, and then two or more digits. It is clear what OP needs, I even edited the title to make it visible for everyone.

Comment: The original question never specified, whether there is a possibility for leading *digits*, only leading characters. This (theoretically) does not mean, that leading digits are not possible. When you changed the title, the meaning of the question subtly changed. However, I agree with you, that your answer is probably what OP wanted. Otherwise I would have posted a competing answer.